# Make synergy work between qemu host and guest

Tags: qemu, synergy

I have a working configuration of a Gentoo as a host and a Windows 10 as a guest using QEMU/KVM with GPU passthrough. I also passthrough my keyboard and mouse, and have a secondary keyboard in a different USB port, which is used by the host.

I have installed Synergy on both operating systems, but even thought they share the same IP, I can't get them to see each other with "localhost". I have read that I should rather use bridges, or tun-tap devices, but I can't really understand what they do and would like a bit of help setting them up.

Finally, here is my qemu startup script:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm /tmp/my_vars.fd
cp /usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF_VARS-pure-efi.fd /tmp/my_vars.fd
export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=pa QEMU_PA_SAMPLES=8192 QEMU_PA_SERVER=127.0.0.1
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-enable-kvm \
-m 6144 \
-smp cores=4,threads=1 \
-soundhw hda \
-usb -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=3 \
-usb -device usb-host,hostbus=1,hostaddr=4 \
-device vfio-pci,host=01:00.0,multifunction=on \
-device vfio-pci,host=01:00.1 \
-drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly,file=/usr/share/edk2.git/ovmf-x64/OVMF_CODE-pure-efi.fd
-device virtio-scsi-pci,id=scsi \
-drive file=/dev/sda5,id=disk,format=raw,if=none -device scsi-hd,drive=disk
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem here is that networking is broken on your VM.  I wouldn't even think about Synergy until you have that fixed.  You say **"they share the same IP"**  That's a problem.  In order for them to communicate with eachother they'll need *different* IP's on the same subnet.

Comment: And how can I achieve that?

Comment: Do you have a DHCP server running or are you assigning IP's manually?

Comment: I have no dhcp server running on my PC, but on my router

Comment: Then I would configure networking on your host to be in 'bridged' mode.  Your VM can get an IP from the router just like any other node on your network and host and guest should be able to communicate.

Comment: Would you mind adding some detail or link or something so I can learn more about bridges?